# Latex - Is it possible to have text on top of images?

Tags: image, latex, pdflatex

I want to create something like a leaflet/magazine using Latex. Is it possible to place text on top of an image and style the text freely?

Any links to examples of something like this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I usually do something like

```
\usepackage{tikz}
...
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{imagefile.png}};
    \draw (1, 1) node {Hello world};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: not very good. If the string for the second is too long, then the string will go beyond the pdf page.

Comment: tqjustc: The issue you mention can be solved by adding the option "text width=20em" to the node.

Comment: What's the purpose of `inner sep=0`?

Comment: The '''inner sep=0''' is to avoid a (white) border around the image.

Answer (score 8):

You can also define the text after the image and then offset it using negative vertical space. Because it follows after the image in the LaTeX source, it will be drawn on top of the image instead of underneath it.

```
\includegraphics[...]{...}
\vspace*{-20ex}  % Tune this to the image height.
\begin{center}
Text
\end{center}
\vspace*{20ex}  % The spacing above but without the minus.
```

Answer (score 6):

A very good toolset for manipulating images is `pgf/TikZ` [pdf doc](http://mixing.coas.oregonstate.edu/links/latex_files/pgfuserguide.pdf).

See `\pgfimage` for examples. It allows to mix text and image freely. There are many ways to do it. One of them is to use `layers` (p. 220 of [pgfmanual](http://maths.dept.shef.ac.uk/magic/latex/pgfmanual.pdf)). The `pgf` manual contains many simple examples, and is very precise.

Another solution is to use the `lpic` package: the [homepage](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~matveyev/lpic/) contains some examples.

You can find other examples for pfg and TikZ [here](http://particlephd.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/latex-figures-with-pgf-and-tikz/) and [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) for many impressive examples.

Answer (score 5):

As already suggested, you can annotate the different parts of the figure [using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/76206). However, sometimes it might even better to use numbers to reference the different parts and explain them in the figure caption.

To easily **get the precise relative positions** (which is often tedious) and to generate LaTeX code automatically, you could use the new web-based [**LaTeX Overlay Generator**](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/), which I built for such cases. This is just a small interactive tool, which helps you to find the right locations.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is the [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/) package which allows you to specify boxes at absolute positions on the page. The boxes can overlap, so you can put the figure in one box, and text in another box on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

I realise that the question is old and answer is accepted, but for completeness would like to propose an alternative approach for making leaflets in LaTeX.

Specifically, the [leaflet](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/leaflet/) document style served me really well for this purpose.

A good blog post wrt background image can be found [here](http://blogs.gnome.org/muelli/2011/01/latex-leaftlet-and-background-colours). There are a couple of packages that are required to use in order to make the proposed approach work, but were not mentioned in the blog post:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, admittedly not using LaTeX, would simply be to edit the image with photoshop or gimp or something like that. I guess your option in terms of typesetting mathematics might be fairly limited doing it this way.

Otherwise I'd endorse using tikz.

Are you sure you want to do it in LaTeX? Desktop publishing software might be more suited to your needs... Something like [scribus](http://www.scribus.net/) might be easier than tikz in terms of learning curve, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add on to @midtiby's answer...

You can also specify the text position using a relative position, like so:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
...
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{imagefile.png}};
    \node[above=0 of image] {Hello world};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```